# Virtumart 2.6 paypal payment currency should be current currency selected by user not default vendor currency

Tags: joomla, paypal, joomla2.5, virtuemart

Hi i am using virtuemart for an eCommerce application. I have used currency selector module of virtuemart to give user facility to change currency accordingly.

Everything is working fine but on product checkout page total product price is showing in the currency which is selected by user but In total payment currency it is showing default vendor currency.

I want to make user pay their payment in the currency which is selected by them not by the default vendor currency. please help.

Here is screenshot. In the screenshot user is selected INR so payment should be in INR not in GBP [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to store the currency choosen by user in Session and then retrieve it on the Payment Page.